# Shap values for xgboost model in tidymodels

Tags: xgboost, tidymodels, shap

I have trained an XGBoost model through the tidymodels metapackage.
I would like some assistance in calculating SHAP values for the model or on how to use the SHAP/fastSHAP packages with the model
TNX
M

Comment: Please consider [ask] and [reprex]

Answer (score 0):

XGBoost already provide Shap values. Here an example of ploting a Shap summary of a XGBoost model from tidymodels. I hope it helps.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(xgboost)
library(SHAPforxgboost)

data(Chicago)
n <- nrow(Chicago)
chicago <- Chicago %>% select(ridership, Clark_Lake, Quincy_Wells)
chicago_train <- chicago[1:(n - 7), ]
chicago_test <- chicago[(n - 6):n, ]

xgb_spec <- 
    boost_tree(mode = "regression", engine = "xgboost") %>% 
    set_args(
      trees = 300,
      learn_rate = 0.2,
      mtry = 0.1,
      sample_size = 0.6,
      counts = FALSE
    )

xgb_fit <- xgb_spec %>% 
  fit(ridership ~ ., data = chicago_train)

chicago_shap <-
  shap.prep(
    xgb_model = extract_fit_engine(xgb_fit),
    X_train = select(chicago_train, -ridership) %>% as.matrix()
  )
  
sps <- shap.plot.summary(chicago_shap)
print(sps)
```

[[image: shap summary plot1]